# Maintain aspect ratio and keep <div> from expanding

Tags: html, css

I have a `<div>` in which I am trying to keep a constant aspect ratio in (because the inner elements will need to be squares). I have been able to work out the CSS so that when you make the window *less* wide, the height will shrink accordingly and that works great. However, when I make the window *more* wide, the `<div>` keeps expanding beyond the height of the parent. How can I stop this `.BoardWrapper` `<div>` from expanding past its parent?

```css
.BoardWrapper {
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 50%;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.Board {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px; bottom: 5px; left: 5px;right: 5px;
    border: 1px solid green;
}

.Left {
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0; right: 30px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

.Right {
    height: 100%;
    width: 20px;
    float: right;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.Container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10vh; bottom: 5vh; left: 5vw; right: 5vw;
}
```

```html
<div class='Container'>
  <div class='Right'></div>
  <div class='Left'>
    <div class='BoardWrapper'>
      <div class='Board'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I do not really want to have to deal with a JS solution here since these are all React components. However, a solution that incorporates React or Semantic-UI would be fine (although, it seems like there should be a raw CSS solution).

I'd prefer not to edit `.Left`, `.Right`, or `.Container`, but I can certainly add in extra elements if it would help.

Comment: `<div class='Right' />` is not a way to close a div tag. What do you need actually ? A square standing in the middle of the left box that never grows bigger than its container ? If yes, flex, margin can do this with less div and no absolute position. https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/WZgzLj

Comment: @G-Cyr In essence, yes, but the aspect ratio actually needs to be 7:6

Comment: okay, then update size according to ratio https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/WZgzLj/ ?? would this be your answer or is there something else not right ?

Comment: @G-Cyr working on it, this is all enclosed in other stuff that complicates things

Comment: Okay, too bad. is it that complexe that you cannot set a snippet close enough to show your issue ?..  calc()then could be involved and absolute position may be relevant.

Comment: @G-Cyr it's kind of working, the left element doesn't "shrink" quickly enough, here's a more accurate codepen of what I'm working with, https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oGPyvB, the right side is all messed up, but I'll fix that later

Comment: okay, yes it is a bit messy, i added some flex display and properties ... the menu does not get resized, so at one point, the left box will overflow ;) https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/oGPyBw

Answer (score 0):

Remove the padding-bottom

```
.BoardWrapper {
  padding-bottom: 50%;
}
```

and add height

```
.BoardWrapper {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Working Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/zwp8vwob/

Comment: That kills the aspect ratio